# Re-Arrange UV slots

Tags: uv, add-on

Is it possible to re-arrange the UV slots, maybe using an addon or...?
I need a specific UV to be on the second slot, but after forgetting to create it & creating four of them I can't move it to the second slot. I don't really want to lose all the work I've done.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hello :). You can add a number prefix before each UV map (like 1. Graphics, 2. Imperfections, 3. Dirt) and then sort them by name. That way you can easily change the order anytime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what do you mean by 'and then sort them by name'..  how could you sort them? the UV Maps slots has no option for sorting, and nothing changes in the ui..  https://ibb.co/7C1gCzv

Comment: @JachymMichal what do say..

Comment: Hey :). Can't post images now. Under the UV maps panel, there's a little white arrow (triangle). Click it and then you can rearrange the items.

Comment: I see! :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As @Jachym Michal said.. You can add a number prefix before each UV map (like 1. Graphics, 2. Imperfections, 3. Dirt) and then sort them by name. That way you can easily change the order anytime

[image]